# UICollectionView with Insets Not Scrolling All the Way Down

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiedgeinsets

I have a `collectionview` with content edge insets 8 pixels from both the top and bottom.

When I invoke `scrollToItemAt` of the collection to the very last item, it scrolls down but is 8 pixels short of the very bottom of the `collectionview`, which I'm assuming has to do with the bottom inset.

I've tried fiddling with the `scrollEdgeInsets` and checked to see if my `viewcontroller` in `storyboard` had the "adjust scroll view insets" unchecked per ([UICollectionView with ContentInset is not Scrolling all the Way Down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993409/uicollectionview-with-contentinset-is-not-scrolling-all-the-way-down)), but still getting the same results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my workaround was increasing the height of the last cell in the collectionViewLayout delegate method.